# Why do I get different status code depending on expressions order?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3. This is the simple code of my endpoint:

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Not Found");
context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
```

I expected to get `400` status code, but I got `200`. However, if I change the code strings order:

```
context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Not Found");
```

then I get `404` status code. Why does the status code value depend on the order of expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WriteAsync` method actually sends out the response, so in the 1st example you are sending the response with the default status code (i.e. 200), and then modifying the status code of the response variable which is then not used further